# What information is contained in series of books called "The Papal Teachings" by The Benedictine Monks of Solesmes?

Tags: catholicism, books, papal-magisterium

I was shopping for a beer stein from the American Chesterton Society store (shameless plug or context, you tell me :) ) and I noticed a few books in one of the pictures advertising it.  I found them on used [in this link](https://www.amazon.com/s?i=stripbooks&rh=p_27%3AThe+Benedictine+Monks+of+Solesmes&s=relevancerank&text=The+Benedictine+Monks+of+Solesmes&ref=dp_byline_sr_book_1) They're called

- Papal Teaching: The Holy Rosary
- Papal Teachings: The Liturgy
- Papal Teachings: The Lay Apostolate

other works appear to be

- Papal Teachings: The Human Body
- Papal Teachings: Directives

maybe a few others.

Just wondering what is in those books.  Lots of people come to this website asking for "What does the Church teach about X" and I can't offer them much more than a google site search of vatican.va.  I'm guessing that's just barely scratching the surface.  Are these an authentic representation of magisterial teaching on subjects that are go deeper than the Catechism?

Answer (score 1):

They're collections of magisterial documents from various popes.

Some are available in e-book format:

- [*The Church*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=8716) (1962)
- [*The Liturgy*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=8717) (1962)
- [*Matrimony*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7502) (1963)

Answer (score 1):

**What information is contained in series of books called "The Papal Teachings" by The Benedictine Monks of Solesmes?**

This series of books are a gathering of papal teachings by the Teaching Magisterium of the Church’s official documents and reflections of various pope’s on various subjects.

For example see the following:

> [The Lay Apostolate; Papal Teachings](https://www.pilgrimreaderbooks.com/product/37159/The-Lay-Apostolate-Papal-Teachings-Benedictine-Monks-Of-Solesmes-selected-and-arranged-by-translated-by-a-secular-priest)
>
> Part of the series of Papal Teachings compiled by the Monks of Solesmes and published by the Daughters of St. Paul. A collection of Papal documents on the lay apostolate presenting the thoughts and reflections of 9 popes - from Benedict XIV to Pius XII. Sixty-eight pages of various indices at the back.

> [Papal Teachings: The Human Body](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0017R9SF8)
>
> This book gathers the teachings of Popes Leo Xlll, Pius Xl and Pius Xll concerning the orgin , value, education, use and destiny of the Human Body.

> [The Holy Rosary (Papal Teaching)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0686743458) June 1, 1980
>
> [Compiled by the] Benedictine Monks of Solesmes

> [Le saint rosaire : présentation et tables](https://www.worldcat.org/title/saint-rosaire-presentation-et-tables/oclc/17587829&referer=brief_results)
>
> Series: Enseignements pontificaux et conciliaires.

> [Le mariage](https://www.worldcat.org/title/mariage/oclc/1150251582&referer=brief_results)
>
> Series: Les Enseignements pontificaux

According to this [site](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=su%3A%22Papal%20documents%22%20AND%20kw%3A%22Abbaye%20Saint-Pierre%20de%20Solesmes%22&fq=&dblist=638&start=1&qt=previous_page), this series of books seems quite impressive to say the least.